How can I modify the content of an ELF file section using ELFIO in C++?
I've been messing around with elf files and the ELFIO library in C++ for a while. I understand how I can add a new section and add data to this particular section. But what if I want to modify the content of this particular section?
From what I understand, each section has a particular size and if the new data exceeds the size of the section it could corrupt other data in the elf file. Do I have to find the offset of this section and its size then try to modify the data in memory? Is this something I could achieve by using the ELFIO library?
This is my code for adding a new section and data into an elf file, and trying to modify the section data:
void writeToELF(std::string& filePath, std::string& str) {
    ELFIO::elfio writer;

    if (!writer.load(filePath)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't find or load ELF file.");
    }

    const std::string sectionName = ".random";
    ELFIO::section* newSection= writer.sections.add(sectionName.c_str());
    newSection->set_type(ELFIO::SHT_PROGBITS);
    newSection->set_flags(ELFIO::SHF_WRITE | ELFIO::SHF_ALLOC);
    newSection->set_addr_align(0x4);
    newSection->set_data(str.data(), str.size());

    writer.set_entry(newSection->get_address());

    const std::string modifiedELF = "modified_" + filePath;
    if (!writer.save(modifiedELF.c_str())) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error saving modified file.");
    }

    std::cout << "Modified ELF saved successfully. " << std::endl;
}

void updateSectionData(std::string& filePath, std::string& sectionName) {
    
    ELFIO::elfio writer;
    if (!writer.load(filePath)) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading file: " << filePath << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ELFIO::section* custom_section = writer.sections[sectionName];
    if (!custom_section) {
        std::cerr << "Section not found." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string newData = "This is a new string";
    custom_section->set_data(newData.data(), newData.size());

    if (!writer.save("modified_" + filePath)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to save modified ELF file." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    
    std::cout << "Content has been updated." << std::endl;

}

int main() {
    std::string fileName = "elf.bin";
    std::string str = "This is new data to be added to a new section.";
    writeToELF(fileName, str);
    
    std::string modified_elf = "modified_elf.bin";
    std::string sectionName = ".customSection";
    updateSectionData(modified_elf, sectionName);
}

The first function writeToElf works as expected. It adds a new section containing the passed in data. I set the flags to SHF_WRITE and SHF_ALLOC because I want this section to be modifiable and to be loaded into memory when executed. The problem is the second function, it doesn't modify the section data like expected. It simply prints out the error messsage "Failed to save modified elf file." and creates an empty file.

Please post a [mre] rather than just code snippets.

what about now?

"what about now?" - That still not a [mre] - at the very least there are some #include"s missing - we cannot just copy'n'paste that code and compile+run it - also; you should try to hardcode any required data so your program won't depend on external data files - make it self contained, complete and minimal.
